# Redirect if not logged in

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP login script and I only want certain pages to be accessed if the user is logged in (if they're not, they're re-directed to the login page).

I have this in login.php which starts the session:

```
<?php

session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","SomeData","Privatestuff");
$User = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_POST['loginsubmit'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);

$logincheck = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $logincheck);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
header('Location: index.php');
die();
}else{
echo "Username or password is invalid.";
}

}
}
}

?>
```

I have this on index.php which redirects the user if they're not logged in, **hover it doesn't prevent users from visiting the page if they're not logged in**

```
<?php

session_start();
$con = DB INFO
$User = $_SESSION['username'];

if(!$User){
header('Location: welcome.php');
die(); 
}

?>
```

Could someone please help determine why users can still visit index.php if they're not logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `index.php`:-

```
<?php
session_start();
// $con = DB INFO //not needed
 //$User = $_SESSION['username']; not needed

if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    // your complete code will be inside this if 
}else{
   header('Location: welcome.php');
   die(); 
 }
?>
```

In `login.php` some enhancement needed which are commented:-

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of errors
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those errors
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","Username","SomeData","Privatestuff");
$User = $_SESSION['username'];

if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) { // check with posted values not with submit button values

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

 //$username = stripslashes($username); //not needed
//$password = stripslashes($password); //not needed

........ rest of your code
```

Comment: May I ask if the `$User = $_SESSION['username'];` is required at the top of the page, as well as when the user logs in?

Comment: you can directly use `$_SESSION['username']` everywhere, but if you want to then use `$User = $_SESSION['username'];`, no problem

Comment: @Anant - Please refrain from asking people to vote for your answers in comments, and please stop asking them to look at your answer in comments under questions. Many of these comments have been flagged and removed, and the community in general regards them as noise.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your `index.php` or header.php

```
<?php
        // First execute a common code to connect to the database and start the session
        include ("includes/connect.php");

        // At the top of the page check to see whether the user is logged in or not
        if(empty($_SESSION['users']))
        {
            // If they are not, redirect them to the login page.
            header("Location: login.php");

            // Remember that this die statement is absolutely critical.  Without it,
            // people can view your members-only content without logging in.
            die("Redirecting to login.php");
        }
    ?>
```

And add or do this one  to your login page or `login.php`.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ('includes/connect.php');

$message="";
if(!empty($_POST["login"])) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $_POST["username"] . "' and password = '". $_POST["password"]."'");
    $row  = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if(is_array($row)) {
        $_SESSION["users"] = $row['usersid'];
        $_SESSION['login'] = true;
        header("Location:index.php");
        exit(); 
    } else {
    $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    }
}
?>
```